# Using validationRules in Models to validate form Codeigniter 4

Tags: model-view-controller, model, controller, codeigniter-4

So I have these variables `$skipValidation` (set specifically to `FALSE`), `$validationRules`, `$validationMessages` set according to [this documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html?highlight=validationrules#setValidationRules)

but for the life of me I can't figure out what trigger this `$validationRules` to run, I just assume that `$skipValidation` meant Codeigniter-4 already got me covered (automatically validates input before doing any queries)..

I even put `$UserModel->errors()` in case the validation rules catch an error

```
if($userModel->insert($data) === false) {
  return view('form', ['validation' => $userModel->errors()])
} else {
  redirect()->to('home');
}
```

I have these rules `required` `and min_length[]` applied to `$validationRules` but the model just skips the validationRules and insert it immediately to database rendering `$validationRules` useless..

Any ideas how to get validationRules in Models working? or how is it supposed to be used? I keep looping in the documentation because I don't know any better.

Comment: Change the code to $userModel->insert($data) === false to $userModel->save($data) === false. This should throw the errors.

Comment: thank you for your response and no, still skips the validation.. i'm assuming its an unresolved bug since i got mysqli exception instead of safely return error message into the variable using $userModel->errors()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb me, i was trying to figure out what is wrong with the code this whole time when its just a simple problem.. i have two models with the same filename (backup project) and i blindly edits model file that is inside the backup project..

Perhaps for future readers seeking an answer, don't forget to check your folder path for your model file, you might make the same mistake as i did.